# Strange NullReferenceException on ExecuteReader

Tags: c#, db2, nullreferenceexception, datareader

when I try to execute the folowing code, a NullReferenceException is raised on the ExecuteReader:

```
static public IDataReader executeReader(string query, string connectionString, string databaseType)
    {
        switch(databaseType)
        {               
            case "SqlServer":
                //stuff for Sql Server      
            case "DB2":
                iDB2Connection myConnectionDB2 = new iDB2Connection(connectionString);

                iDB2Command sqlCommandDB2 = new iDB2Command(query,  myConnectionDB2);
                sqlCommandDB2.CommandTimeout=0;
                try
                {                       
                    sqlCommandDB2.Connection.Open();
***The exception is raised here...***
                    return sqlCommandDB2.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    sqlCommandDB2.Dispose();
                    myConnectionDB2.Close();
                    throw new Exception("Error in DBHelper:ExeSQL()-> " + e.ToString());
                }       
            default:
                //stuff for Oracle
        }                           
    }
```

Here is the message exception:

> System.NullReferenceException: La référence d'objet n'est pas définie
>   à une instance d'un objet. at
>   Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.CopyMemoryUni(StringBuilder pdst, IntPtr
>   psrc, IntPtr sizetcb) at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringUni(IntPtr ptr) at
>   IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.MPHostCol.setHostColInfo(MpDcHostColumnInfo
>   dcHostColInfo)
>   blahblahblah until the line above.

Every parameter is filled, the query execute correctly with SQL-view, the connection string is correct and the database type is ok...
As every static method, nothing else have to be set... i'm sure it's somethin' stupid, but can't figure what.

Comment: Where are you setting the `sql` variable?  Did you mean to use the `query` variable passed into the function?

Comment: Judging by the stack trace, this may be a library problem (`IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries`), assuming your `sql` is set and valid as Peter notes above.

Comment: The iSeries drivers can be really weird sometimes. Make you are fulled patched and updated. We had alot of issues like this before finding out we where a couple updates behind.

Comment: My iSeries dll is V5R3, i try an update to V5R4... I'll let you know.

Comment: It looks like the `IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries` Data Provider falls over in a very ungraceful way when copying a unicode string from some memory at `IntPtr psrc` to `StringBuilder pdst`. That string would contain as many bytes as the number pointed to by `IntPtr sizetcb`. I'm guessing that the string builder has not been instantiated. Either you need to call the DB2 data provider in a different way or get a different version that works more elegantly.

Comment: Wait a while and you'll be able to answer your question (and I'll upvote the answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn, the update from V5R3 to V5R4 has solved the bug. A simple 15 minutes update solved 3 days of head banging. Glad to have contributed :)

Comment: Theres plenty of other weird things those drivers can do trust me. My favorite personally, is when the estimator decides that your query might run longer then the timeout, so it simply returns immediately without executing anything, but with no error or exception. Just an empty dataset.

Comment: Oh, and it looks like the newest version (I hope) is V6R1M0.

Comment: IMO, DB2 is a big wtf itself. We'll upgrade to the V6 when all our server will be ready, which mean maybe in december. Or next year.